# No Webcam Device

Tags: 12.04, webcam

```
deeva@androliyah-A6200:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for deeva: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e080(size=8)
deeva@androliyah-A6200:~$
```

How do I get my webcam to work?

Comment: Please provide an answer via separate post below.

Answer (score 9):

If your laptop is like mine, you have what is called a "function" button (mine is located next to my "Ctrl" button). This button says "Fn" on it. You can use this button to enable/disable things via keyboard.

The whole time, my webcam was disabled. I had to press my Fn button + the webcam button (button should have a webcam on it, just like the bluetooth has the bluetooth symbol on it and so forth).

**Solution - Press Fn+Webcam Button.**
Your webcam light should now switch on when using apps that allow webcam use.

Comment: Oh my goodness... I've been struggling for months. Can not believe it's that simple. Thank you

Comment: Youre welcome beanaroo. Can you vote my answer up if it worked for you? Thanx.

Comment: if that worked for you make sure to mark the answer as accepted and give it a thumbs up ;)

Comment: best.laptopwebcam.answer.ever  worked for me!